# Hyperlinks appear as links but not clickable

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I have been trying to send out emails from my server using PHP but the hyperlinks in email are not clickable.

They appear blue just like normal links but they are not linked.

This is what I have:

```
$subject = "Email subject";
$l="http://www.example.com/Oa7dl";

$txt="<a href'$l' target='_blank' title='CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE AND APPLY'><img src='http://www.example.com/pics/click_here.png' alt='CLICK HERE TO LEARN MORE AND APPLY' /></a> or FOLLOW LINK: <a href'$l' target='_blank'>http://example.com/Oa7dl</a>";
```

This will be sent as a body of an email message.

[image: hyperlink error screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<a href='$l'` not `<a href'$l'`

You missed the `=`

Answer (score 3):

Subtituting variable for its value would result in :

```
href'http://www.goo.gl/Oa7dl'
```

This means you are missing a `=` after href. It should be:

`href='http://www.goo.gl/Oa7dl'` or `href='$l'`